# Setting up passive FTP (IIS6) on Windows Server 2003

Tags: iis-6, ftp

I am having trouble setting up passive FTP on IIS 6. I used this instruction: http://www.velikan.net/iis-passive-ftp/

When I tried to upload a file through the FTP, I got the error:

```
425 Can't open data connection. : /index.html
```

The interesting thing is that from the server, I can see the index.html file is already created but the file size is set to 0.

I am using the FireFTP client. I opened the FTP passive ports for 1024-1048.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the passive port range and opened the ports on the server and any intermediate firewall? (allowing connections on those ports from client to server)

Have you allowed the ports/application in your local firewall? (allowing connections outwards)

In the FTP client log does it say PASV at some point?

The command to create the file is sent on the port 21 connection, the additional port is the one for data.  So creating a 0kb file just shows that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check-

1. Make sure the client is making PASV connections. Check the ftp client logs to see if is sending PASV command before retrieving any data.
2. FTP passive ports are NOT 1024-1048, the server randomly picks any ports above 1024, as far as i know.